# How is it easier to navigate in Sub-Folder in modern experience?

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, modern-experience

I saw this post [here](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/7081553-make-an-easier-way-to-navigate-up-when-you-are-in) and I know that the modern experience is to be better and more user friendly but how exactly is it easier to navigate through folders using it.

We still use the folder structure  and there a  lot of subfolders so navigating isn’t that pleasant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint Online Modern Experience, As we navigate into folders and sub folders, it adds link to the parent folder in Breadcrumb above List/Library View.

I have created 4 Level subfolders in document library.

**Modern Experience:**

[image]

While in Classic experience, we get the link of parent (only 1 level).

**Classic Experience:**

[image]

Comment: thank a lot this helps a lot

Comment: Welcome, Keep exploring and learning :)